# Write to CSV without including (") in each record

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've shaped the data with pandas. And when I write to csv, there's the (") at the start and end of the row in the file.

```
"A|ColA|ColB|ColC|"
"A|val1|val2|val3|"
"A|val4|val5|val6|"
```

How do I write to csv such that the file becomes like this?

```
A|ColA|ColB|ColC|
A|val1|val2|val3|
A|val4|val5|val6|
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` and what is your code that exports to the csv.

Comment: print(df.head().to_dict()) gives me:

{'combined' : {0: 'val1|val2|val3', 1:"val4|val5|val6"}}

and my code to export to csv is this:

df.to_csv("mytext.txt", index = False, header = False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe already contains the quotes as part of the field and `|` was not recognized as a field separator. Was that intended? 
If you want to force pandas just not to use quotes when writing, you can use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` as follows:

```
import csv
df.to_csv("mytext.txt", index = False, header = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

If you want to read it in again later into separate colums, you can do that like this:

```
pd.read_csv('mytext.txt', sep='|')
```